# Determining controller based on post data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application I have a form with radio type inputs and post method. The user selects one of these radio options and submits the form. How could I set the routing such (in `routes.rb` or in some other way) that the controller would be selected based on the value of the selected input value which is now in the post data. In `routes.rb` the `params` hash isn't available, but could I access this data in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to my mind:

1. Use JavaScript to intercept the submit action. On submit, read the value of the selected radio option, change the target attribute of the form to the URL you expect to be used and submit the form.

   To make the JavaScript unobtrusive, the URL of the target can be added as a `data-target` attribute to the radio options. In this way, once you get the selected value, you just replace the form target with the value of `data-target`. The benefit is that you can generate it server side and you don't have to hard-code the value.
2. Use an intermediate action. Always submit the form to an action that reads the payload and redirects to the relevant controller action based on the payload value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Those both would accomplish what I want in practice but I'm looking to find a direct solution without having to do "extra" things.

Comment: There is no direct solution as what you want to accomplish requires to correlate server side with client side, but these two aspects of an application work at different level in different time.

Comment: Right, so I guess it would require then to dynamically change the application routing based on the current request if a specific route is requested.